# Two conflicting X-Powered-By headers

Tags: php, asp.net, http, iis, http-headers

Recently I was curious about the technology that certain site was using, so I have taken a look at the headers. To my joy, what appeared was:

```
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
```

I am curious: what else, in addition to just overriding the headers (eg. for obfuscation/security purposes), could lead the web application to produce such response headers? Assuming that the site developers / administrators did not manipulate mentioned headers, what is the case for such response headers to appear?

If this helps in any way, maybe some other returned headers will help:

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1250
```

(the rest of the headers look pretty normal, so I am not listing them)

I am not asking the question on whether I can run PHP on IIS etc., rather about what possible scenarios could result in such two `X-Powered-By` headers. Maybe some reverse proxy (written in PHP, serving pages generated by ASP.NET)?

Comment: i would not assume what you have chosen to assume

Comment: @Dagon: That is pretty obvious answer and I am interested in the answers saying what I have assumed is right. Your comment says exactly the opposite to what I expect (which is okay, unless someone gives a case when my assumption may be right).

Comment: I don't know why, but IIS displays both headers on PHP pages, but only the ASP.NET header on ASP.NET pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that it is pretty normal for a IIS server to serve both ASP.NET (should be nearly built-in) and additionally PHP as a module. ASP files with `.aspx`, PHP with `.php`.

Comment: So you are saying `X-Powered-By` here does not say what solutions were used to generate the page, rather what solutions are available on the server?

Comment: Yes. If PHP is registered as a server module, it can be configured to add such a header. The same might be true for ASP.NET.

Comment: I am then assuming this is the case: neither PHP nor ASP.NET needs to be used to generate such headers in automated way on IIS. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that this is describing not the page, but the webserver - i.e. that the web server has both ASP.NET installed, AND php.